# How to modify a record before saving on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking for a way to either:

- Change one of the fields of a new record (namely - force it to lower-case) before saving it to a RoR db.
  I've tried:

  before_create do |term|
  term.myfield.downcase!
  end

but this gives an error of:

```
undefined method `before_create' for RowsController:Class
```

or

- Check that the field is all lowercase, and if not, raise an error message, and not create the record.

tried:

```
before_filter :check_lowcase, :only => [:new]
def check_lowcase
  if (Term.new =~ /[^a-z]+/)
    flash[:notice] = "Sorry, must use lowercase"
    redirect_to terms_path
  end
end
```

this seems to just be ignored....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do it on your model, not your controller:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_create :downcase_stuff

  private
    def downcase_stuff
      self.myfield.downcase!
     end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! it works!
What if I wanted to raise an error message, instead of correcting it?

Comment: Just add in: errors.add(:myfield, "must be lowercase" ). Although this should really go in a validation not a before_create filter

Comment: and how would I put this in a validator? is there a validator that accepts a custom function?

Answer (score 0):

```
    before_create :lower_case_fields

    def lower_case_fields
       self.myfield.downcase!
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

`before_save { |classname| classname.myfield = myfield.downcase }`